# "I don't know French, but I can learn!"

Tags: traduction

I have an interview coming up and found out it will be for the company's Paris office. I don't know French and I'm certain they'll ask me about it (though the company itself does business in English). I'd at least like to have a clever phrase under my belt such as "I don't know French, but I can certainly learn!" What's the proper way to say that phrase in French? Merci :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Je ne parle pas français, mais je peux apprendre !

Comment: Ne faut-il faire une référence en français de quelque façon ? `Je ne parle pas français, mais je peux l'apprendre !` ou `Je ne parle pas français, mais je peux en apprendre !`

Comment: *Je peux apprendre* will mean you are ready to learn, it just implies it refers to French. *Je peux l'apprendre* clarifies it is the French  language you talking about, the difference will not be very big. But *je peux en apprendre* is not grammatical if talking about only one language.

Comment: @Greg : Merci ! C'est clair.

Comment: @dimitris Il est vrai qu'un pronom est souvent souhaitable, voire obligatoire, dans ce type de phrase mais ici, *mais je peux apprendre* est plus courant que *mais je peux l'apprendre*, c'est presque devenu une expression idiomatique figée. Elle a aussi l'avantage d'éviter à l'oral la confusion avec *mais je peux la prendre*.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci vivement. Personnellement, je voudrais suggérer la proposition : `J'ai la volonté d'apprendre le français" mais n'étant pas francophone je n'en suis pas comment s'écoute:-)!

Comment: *J'ai la volonté d'apprendre le français* est un peu lourd à l'oral mais grammaticalement correct. En revanche, *je n'en suis pas comment s'écoute* n'est ni grammatical, ni compréhensible...

Comment: @jlliagre :   Oh ! Désolé ! J'aurais dû écris << je n'en suis sûr pas comment ça s'écoute >>. À vrai dire je me demande encore si la proposition est correcte ou pas:-)!

Comment: @dimitris Toujours pas çà :-) *Je ne suis pas sûr que ça sonne bien* peut-être ?

Comment: @jlliagre : D'accord ! C'est bein ça :-)!

Comment: Maybe `Je ne parle pas français, mais je peux toujours l'apprendre` which provides the same meaning that `I can certainly learn`.

Comment: @Solostaran14 `Je peux toujours l'apprendre` is slightly less positive than `I can certainly learn`. I'd rather translate the latter as `je peux tout à fait l'apprendre` or `je peux bien sûr l'apprendre`.